# PL/SQL : How to display subject title and lecturer names in a procedure?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, procedure

My procedure will take in an subject code as a parameter and the proceed to display the subject title and lecturers’ names who have taught the subject before 2016. My procedure should also prompt input a subject code and display the results. I tried my code as following without putting it into a procedure and it returns the correct results but when I include my code as part of a PL/SQL procedure, I get an error that says

> Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

I am quite new to PL/SQL so any advices would be helpful! The procedure code that I had been trying for hours as follow:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WHO(CODE CHAR)
IS
FNAME VARCHAR(256)
LNAME VARCHAR(256)
TITLE VARCHAR(256)

CURSOR C1
IS
    SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SUBJECT.NAME
    FROM ACADEMIC INNER JOIN TEACHES
    ON STAFF# = LECTURER
    INNER JOIN SUBJECT
    ON TEACHES.CODE=SUBJECT.CODE
    WHERE YEAR<2016 AND TEACHES.CODE=CODE
    GROUP BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SUBJECT.NAME;
BEGIN
    OPEN C1;
    LOOP
    IF C1%NOTFOUND THEN EXIT;
    END IF;
    FNAME=FIRST_NAME;
    LNAME=LAST_NAME;
    DBMS.OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FNAME||' '||LNAME);
    TITLE=SUBJECT.NAME;
    DBMS.OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TITLE);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE C1;
END WHO;
/
```

Comment: I would have to display the subject name which is unfortunately is placed at another table called subject. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: can you change DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINT to DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I tried but still the same errror :(

Comment: What tool are you using to develop PL/SQL? You need to find out how to use it to see compilation errors, even if it's just querying `user_errors`.  SQL Developer etc will highlight them interactively. SQL*Plus has a `show errors` command, etc.

Comment: Not your compilation error, but `teaches.code = code` should be `teaches.code = who.code` (or else use an industry-standard naming convention for parameter naming such as `p_code`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools like SQL Developer, PL/SQL Developer etc will highlight compilation errors, or on the SQL*Plus command line you can enter

```
show errors
```

immediately after compiling, or else

```
show errors procedure who
```

Or you can query the `user_errors` table. Whatever tool you are using, you need to be able to work with compilation errors.

Start by tidying up the code so it is easier to read and follow and generally looks more professional. Also although they are not actually causing any errors, you should really change those `char` and `varchar` types to the standard `varchar2` (ideally everything should be anchored as `academic.first_name%type` etc, but one thing at a time).

Here is the fixed version:

```
create or replace procedure who
    ( code subject.code%type )  -- CHAR is a disastrous datatype you should never need
is
    fname varchar2(50);  -- VARCHAR2 is the standard string type, VARCHAR is reserved
    lname varchar2(50);  -- Also PL/SQL requires terminating semicolons here
    title varchar2(256);

    cursor c1 is
        select first_name
             , last_name
             , subject.name
        from   academic
               join teaches
                    on  staff# = lecturer
               join subject
                    on  teaches.code = subject.code
        where  year < 2016
        and    teaches.code = who.code  -- "code" on its own is ambiguous
        group by first_name, last_name, subject.name;

begin
    open c1;
    loop
        fetch c1 into fname, lname, title;  -- Added 'fetch into'

        if c1%notfound then
            exit;
        end if;

        dbms_output.put_line(fname || ' ' || lname);  -- It's dbms_output, with a '_'
        dbms_output.put_line(title);
    end loop;

    close c1;
end who;
```

This compiles. 
But you can still simplify this by using a [Cursor FOR Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html) instead of the elaborate, verbose way:

```
create or replace procedure who
    ( code subject.code%type )
is
begin
    for r in (
        select first_name
             , last_name
             , subject.name as title
        from   academic
               join teaches
                    on  staff# = lecturer
               join subject
                    on  teaches.code = subject.code
        where  year < 2016
        and    teaches.code = who.code
        group by first_name, last_name, subject.name
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.first_name || ' ' || r.last_name);
        dbms_output.put_line(r.title);
    end loop;
end who;
```

This implicitly declares a cursor and a record named `r` with the three fields based on the cursor, and it handles opening, fetching and closing for you.

I don't know your tables, but I am guessing they are something like this:

```
create table subject
( code        varchar2(20) primary key
, name        varchar2(30) not null );

create table academic
( staff#      integer primary key
, first_name  varchar2(20) not null
, last_name   varchar2(20) not null );

create table teaches
( lecturer    references academic(staff#) not null
, code        references subject not null
, year        number(4,0) not null
, constraint teaches_pk primary key (lecturer, code, year) );
```

If so, I would use table aliases in the query as below to avoid ambiguity:

```
select a.first_name
     , a.last_name
     , s.name as title
from   academic a
       join teaches t
            on  t.lecturer = a.staff#
       join subject s
            on  s.code = t.code
where  t.year < 2016
and    t.code = who.code
group by a.first_name, a.last_name, s.name
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to debug the errors that I was getting and the extra advices that you gave were really helpful! Sorry if i didnt format it that professionally since I just had only learnt PL/SQL. Thanks for being my lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

You have few issues with your code. Some missing semilcons at decalration. See below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WHO( CODE CHAR)
IS
  FNAME VARCHAR(256); --<Missing Semicolon
  LNAME VARCHAR(256); --<Missing Semicolon
  TITLE VARCHAR(256); --<Missing Semicolon

  CURSOR C1
  IS
    SELECT FIRST_NAME,
      LAST_NAME,
      SUBJECT.NAME
    FROM ACADEMIC
    INNER JOIN TEACHES
    ON STAFF# = LECTURER
    INNER JOIN SUBJECT
    ON TEACHES.CODE =SUBJECT.CODE
    WHERE YEAR      <2016
    AND TEACHES.CODE=CODE
    GROUP BY FIRST_NAME,
      LAST_NAME,
      SUBJECT.NAME;
BEGIN
  OPEN C1;
  LOOP    
    --this is how you put the value of cursor to variable
    FETCH C1 into FNAME ,LNAME ,TITLE ;

    --No need for IF to exit loop. You can use as shown below
    EXIT when C1%NOTFOUND;    

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FNAME||' '||LNAME);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINT(TITLE);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C1;
END WHO;
/
```

Demo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WHO( CODE CHAR)
IS  
  FNAME number;  
  CURSOR C1
  IS
    SELECT contract_id FROM TX;

BEGIN
  OPEN C1;
  LOOP    
    fetch c1 into FNAME;
    EXIT when C1%NOTFOUND;    

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FNAME);

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C1;
END WHO;
/
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
```

Comment: :'( you were faster. Perhaps add a variable-assignment `:=` he has those typos also..

Comment: Thanks for the advices on the typos! But sadly I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: @WendyChong What error you are talking about. See the DEMO which is working. Check if your query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your going the correct direction, but there are a bunch of typos..

But to your main-question:

You have to `FETCH` the rows into you variables. Here an example.

```
DECLARE
    FNAME   VARCHAR (256); -- you need some semicolons here ;)
    LNAME   VARCHAR (256);
    NAME    VARCHAR (256);
    TITLE   VARCHAR (256);

    CURSOR C1 -- replaced you query with a dummy-query. Yours should also work
    IS
        SELECT 'Hans' FIRST_NAME, 'Schnitzel' LAST_NAME, 'The Schnitzel' NAME
          FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Heinrich' FIRST_NAME, 'Wurst' LAST_NAME, 'The Sausage' NAME
          FROM DUAL;
BEGIN
    OPEN C1; -- open cursor

    LOOP
        FETCH C1 INTO FNAME, LNAME, NAME; -- try to read the row and put the values into our variables

        IF C1%NOTFOUND -- check if we got a row
        THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Name: ' || FNAME || ' ' || LNAME); -- work with is.
        TITLE := NAME;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Title: ' || TITLE);
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE C1;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advices on the typos! But sadly I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: What version are u running? Which row has the error? Can you run my example?